# About API Demo Remote Service example in android

Tags: android

I am studying RemoteService example in Android's APISample.  In the
manifest file, it declares the service like this:
My question is how can I specify the service to be 'auto-start', i.e.
it gets start whenever the phone start?

```
    <service android:name=".app.RemoteService" android:process=":remote" >
           <intent-filter>
               <!-- These are the interfaces supported by the service, which
                    you can bind to. -->
               <action
android:name="com.example.android.apis.app.IRemoteService" />
               <action
android:name="com.example.android.apis.app.ISecondary" />
               <!-- This is an action code you can use to select the service
                    without explicitly supplying the implementation class. -->
                   <action android:name="com.example.android.apis.app.REMOTE_SERVICE" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [you do not want to do that](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/).

Second, you cannot do that directly. You will need to set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast `Intent`, and have that receiver start the service.